# When I want all those zeros, I'll ask for them

Tags: clojure, floating-point, number-formatting

Is there some global way in Clojure to set the default format for floating-point numbers?

Often I have floating-point numbers inside nested collections. To take a small example, this expression,

```
(str " -> " linkvec)
```

evaluated on a couple vectors in some code I'm working on right now, produces:

```
 -> [:source1 :output 0.2 0.2 1]
 -> [:source100 :output 0.6000000000000001 0.6000000000000001 100]
```

Most of the time, I don't care about the little round-off errors that show up 16 digits after the decimal point. I'd prefer to have all floating-point output rounded off to the nearest 0.001, with trailing zeros removed after the rounding. So, the above would come out looking like this:

```
 -> [:source1 :output 0.2 0.2 1]
 -> [:source100 :output 0.6 0.6 100]
```

Notice that the desired output is `0.6 0.6`, not `0.600 0.600`.

Of course I could define a function something like:

```
(defn sigfigs [x]
  (format "%.3f" (-> x (* 1000) (math/round) (/ 1000.0))))
```

But then I'd have to call it from everywhere. It would be nice if I could set the default number-formatter to `sigfigs` or something like it, so that `str`, `println`, etc. would call that unless I explicitly format with `%f`. Otherwise, every time I make or print a string involving a collection containing floating-point numbers, I'll have to call code to generate a modified version of that collection where the numbers are trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `str` can be altered (it just invokes toString), but for `print`/`println` you can do this using undocumented [print-method](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/print-method) multimethod:

```
(defmethod print-method java.lang.Double [value ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w (.format (java.text.DecimalFormat. "0.###") value)))
```